# Create a loop for pasting or removing elements based on different scenarios

Tags: r

Say I have the following data set:

```
mydf <- data.frame( "MemberID"=c("111","0111A","0111B","112","0112A","113","0113B"),
                    "resign.date"=c("2013/01/01",NA,NA,"2014/03/01",NA,NA,NA))
```

Note: 111,112 and 113 are the IDs for the family representative.

I would like to do two things:

a) if I have the resign dates for a family representative for instance in the case of 111, I want to paste the same resign dates for 0111A and 0111B (These represent spouse and children of 111 if you're wondering)
b) if I don't have resign dates for the family representative, for instance 113, I would simply like to remove the rows 113 and 0113B.

My resulting data frame should look like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame("MemberID"=c("111","0111A","0111B","112","0112A"),
                    "resign.date"=c("2013/01/01","2013/01/01","2013/01/01","2014/03/01","2014/03/01"))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `resign.date ` only for MemberIDs without trailing letters?

Comment: @simone Yes resign.date is only present for memberIDs without trailing letters.

Comment: in that case, see if solution below is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `resign.date` is only present for (some) `MembersID` without trailing letters, a solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table( "MemberID"=c("0111","0111A","0111B","0112","0112A","0113","0113B"),
                "resign.date"=c("2013/01/01",NA,NA,"2014/03/01",NA,NA,NA)) 

df <- df[order(MemberID)] ## order data : MemberIDs w/out trailing letters first by ID
df[, myID := gsub("\\D+", "", MemberID)] ## create myID col : MemberID w/out trailing letters

df[ , my.resign.date := resign.date[1L], by = myID] ##assign first occurrence of resign date by myID
df <- df[!is.na(my.resign.date)] ##drop rows if my.resign.date is missing
```

**EDIT**

If inconsistencies in `MemberID` (some have leading 0 some don't) you can try some work around as in what follows

```
df <- data.table( "MemberID"=c("111","0111A","0111B","112","0112A","113","0113B"),
              "resign.date"=c("2013/01/01",NA,NA,"2014/03/01",NA,NA,NA)) 

df[, myID := gsub("(?<![0-9])0+", "", gsub("\\D+", "", MemberID), perl = TRUE)]
df <- df[order(myID, -MemberID)]

df[ , my.resign.date := resign.date[1L], by = myID]
df <- df[!is.na(my.resign.date)]
```

Comment: Yes it works. I've never worked with data.table before. Could you tell me what line 3 and 4 does.

Comment: Also, the actual file has a few inconsistencies for instance, sometimes the ID is '113' and the spouse/children ID would be '0113A' and '0113B'. A better code would perhaps be to search for "113" and perform paste and/or remove operations on IDs with trailing letters. I have edited my question.

Comment: I'm glad. You should accept the answer if it's what you were after

Comment: I'm new here. What do you mean by 'accept the answer'? Do I just click on 'the answer was useful' coz I already did that

Comment: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in". [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
     group_by(grp = parse_number(MemberID)) %>% 
     mutate(resign.date = first(resign.date)) %>% 
     na.omit() %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     select(-grp)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   MemberID resign.date
#    <fctr>      <fctr>
#1     0111  2013/01/01
#2    0111A  2013/01/01
#3    0111B  2013/01/01
#4     0112  2014/03/01
#5    0112A  2014/03/01
```